# Positioning bar plot - d3

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to write a reusable plot in d3. the plot type is dependent on the data and share axis, labels , grid etc.

I'm having trouble positioning my bars bottom up. I haven't had any trouble with the line so it seems strange. I think my problem is with this section

```
// plot area
    var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .classed("analysis-line-line", true);
```

The plot area is higher then it should be but I don't understand how come the line is fine.

I would appreciate any guidance. 
Full example in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jPW3X/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove gap between axis, this is what I did:

```
svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "analysis-line-axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (yscale.range()[0] + margin.top) + ")")
        .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(xscale).orient("bottom"));
```

Instead of using height, I think you will have to use (0.9*height + margin.top).

To adjust bars to properly align with axis, you will have to translate them up.

```
rects.attr("transform","translate(0,"+ -(0.1*height) + ")")
```

### Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jPW3X/2/).

Previous answer:

The place where you render bars you will have to subtract margin.top as well from the height calculation:

```
.attr("height", function(d) { return height - yscale(d) - margin.top; })
```

Updated [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/jPW3X/1/)

Comment: Thanks man but a quick follow up to what led me here in the first place - if i set the y range to 0-height the minimum bar in not showing (the value in the range is set to zero). so i set the range to `range([height * 0.9, 0]);` so that the minimum bar will take up 10% of the height. If you'll look closely you'll see that there is gab betwwen the axis - if you set it higher, to 0.8-0.7  it's getting more obvious. how can i overcome this ?

Comment: It looks great - the gap closed but now the axis is incorrect - notice bar B - the value is 123 but it looks more like 150. maybe you could explain this to me - when i set up a rectangle area (p in my case) I should specify three variables x (margin.left) , y (margin.top) and height - but the translate accepts only two (x & y).

Comment: translate just moves a svg element around. It doesn't changes its x and y. so if you say put an element at (3,4) and then u say translate it by (0,2). The end result will be (3,6). I hope this explains.

Comment: Looks at this fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/jPW3X/3/). Is this OK?

Instead of setting range as 0.9*height. I set the starting domain value as 0.9*minVal and range as (height,0). This means your min val will never be zero, unless it is zero in reality.

Comment: Thank you very much @Yogesh - I'll accept that - I appreciate the trouble. One thing though, changing the domain is less "robust" then modified the range. take for example close values for the y values - 10000,10001,100002 - you'll see that the graph becomes useless because the y values starts at 90000 and the bars are very close in height. if you change the range you'll be able to see a difference.